# RSpec message expectations not being met

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'

describe PaymentProcessor do
  before(:each) do
    @processor = PaymentProcessor.new
  end

  describe '#process' do
    context 'payment accepted, sha digest valid' do
      it 'should return true and have no errors' do
        GamePlayResult.stub(:new).and_return(mock('GamePlayResult'))
        ticket = stub_model(Ticket, player: stub_model(Player, has_funds?: true))
        Ticket.stub(:find).and_return ticket
        game = stub_model(Game, play: ticket, tolerance: 10)
        query = 'orderID=1060&STATUS=5&PAYID=17314217&NCERROR=0&SHASIGN=E969563B64ED6F93F5DC47A86B1B04DFC884B4A7'
        @processor.process(query, game).should_not be_false
        game.should_receive(:play)
        @processor.error.should equal nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

All assertions other other than `game.should_receive(:play)` are being met. However i know that `:play` is being called, as a) the other assertions would fail if it wasnt and b) if I don't stub it, I get a unexpected message error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your RSpec expectation **before** you call your code that will execute that expectation.

So this:

```
@processor.process(query, game).should_not be_false
game.should_receive(:play)
```

Should be changed to this:

```
game.should_receive(:play)
@processor.process(query, game).should_not be_false
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to see what code is actually being called here, but judging from what's there I assume that it's this line:

```
@processor.process(query, game).should_not be_false
```

If so, then the problem is that your expectation is coming *after* you run your code, which won't work. Move the `game.should_receive(:play)` line above the `@processor.process(query, game)` line and it should pass:

```
  it 'should return true and have no errors' do
    GamePlayResult.stub(:new).and_return(mock('GamePlayResult'))
    ticket = stub_model(Ticket, player: stub_model(Player, has_funds?: true))
    Ticket.stub(:find).and_return ticket
    game = stub_model(Game, play: ticket, tolerance: 10)
    query = 'orderID=1060&STATUS=5&PAYID=17314217&NCERROR=0&SHASIGN=E969563B64ED6F93F5DC47A86B1B04DFC884B4A7'
    game.should_receive(:play)
    @processor.process(query, game).should_not be_false
    @processor.error.should equal nil
  end
```